# compile part of code using -std=c11 flag

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

Is there a possibility to compile one part of a code with different flags - **without** changing the flags in the makefile?

I've got an existing project which is not set up for -std=c11. Now I have added my own code and the compiler tells me things like

`'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 or C11 mode`

when I change the flag to std=c11 or c99, the rest of the program wont compile anymore.

Is there something like `extern "C" {}` in C++ to tell the compiler to treat the following part as std=c11?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want the rest of the program in C11 though? If you have no requirement that the code must be in C90, then the proper solution is to convert it all to C11. Shouldn't be that much of an effort. Because if you get compiler errors for picking `-std=c11`, then that's a strong indicator of code smell, like for example accidentally using non-standard features or invoking poorly-defined behavior.

Comment: yes, it is a huge project which has not been programmed by me...

Comment: If it's a huge project and changing the compiler options isn't feasible, just code to C90 standards.

Comment: You should be able to add a specific make rule for your files, using whatever compiler flags you want. How you do that will depend on the Makefile.

Comment: If the project uses automake, see https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-and-Library-Variables.html#Program-and-Library-Variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't set compiler options locally. You can however disable spurious warnings locally, by using [diagnostic pragmas](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html).

However, the best way to do this is probably to isolate the C99/C11 code in separate .c files, which you compile separately from the rest of the project, before linking it all together.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a pragma to locally force `-std=c99`/`-std=c11` (even though you can do the equivalent for some other options, e.g., for the `-On` options), but you can pretty much have a for-loop-local initializing declaration even in C90 without much of a syntactic disruption. Just enclose the for loop in braces and place the declaration there: `{ int i=0; for(;i<5;i++){ something(); } }`